Is there a DMV that tells me what type of certificate is used in the current database connections
I need to know if the certificate signed externally , added to the SQL service and given to the application is actually being used because MS has a nasty habit of creating self-signed sha1 certificates in older supported version and these are deemed insecure these days.
My aim is to force the apps to use the correct certificate and to identify those app connections which aren't using the appropriate certificate.
I have searched the internet and DMVs and can't find the information.

If you don't want to connect to a server that uses a self-signed certificate, then ensure you have Encrypt set to True and aren't connecting with TrustServerCertificate set to True. Then the connection will fail. The certificate isn't stored in SQL Server, so you can't query it from SQL Server.

encrypt_option sys.dm_exec_connections will at least tell you if ssl is used at all. Otherwise i'm not sure you can see this info. Perhaps one can sniff that stuff out using wireshark.

It appears in  sys.dm_exec_connections when i force encryption at the service level all connections will say encrypted YES regardless of the client configuraiton. If the client is not set to encrypted  it creates a self-signed cert for them to encrypt the conection.

I am looking to catch the apps not using the cert linked to the SQL service. I am staggered that MS don't have a view that tells you this.

Whether the certificate is self-signed, you can't get it in TSQL, it's only available from the registry.
You can use Powershell though. Set the instance name on the first line or use a loop.
$instancename = YourInstanceHere;
$thumprint = Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\$instancename\MSSQLServer\SuperSocketNetLib" -Name Certificate;
if ($thumprint -eq $null)
{
    "No certificate set";
}
else
{
    $cert = (dir -Path cert:\$thumprint -Recurse)[0];
    if ($cert -eq $null)
    {
        "No certificate found";
    else
    {
        "Is Self Signed $($cert.Subject -eq $cert.Issuer)";
    }
}

Note that the server only checks the registry at startup, so may be using an old certificate if it hasn't been restarted since it was changed.

If you want to know whether connections are using encryption, you can query sys.dm_exec_connections.encrypt_option
select
  c.session_id,
  c.encrypt_option,
  c.client_net_address,
  s.host_name,
  s.database_id,
  s.login_name
from sys.dm_exec_connections c
join sys.dm_exec_sessions s on s.session_id = c.session_id;


Thanks for the reply. I think this does not tell me what certificate each of my instance level connections are using . It tells me if i have added a certificate to the SQL service.

You can check each instance. There is only one certificate used on each instance. But see edit, you can check if the connection is encrypted at all.
